# Segwit: Does the nodes saves 2 types of blocks (or atleast in the past)

Tags: block, segregated-witness

Was wondering for a long why mempool.space was showing blocks greater than 1mb!

Started digging deeper and read these:

- https://jimmysong.medium.com/understanding-segwit-block-size-fd901b87c9d4
- https://jimmysong.medium.com/segwit2x-what-you-need-to-know-about-the-2mb-hard-fork-27749e1544ce

Able to understand the difference between block size and block weight.

Now few questions

- To support the legacy nodes, the upgraded Segwit node will be checking the version of each peer. And if its a legacy node, a trimmed down version of the block will be sent to it. Right?
- Is this stripping down of blocks happens on the fly? or both versions of the block are saved on the disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To support the legacy nodes, the upgraded Segwit node will be checking the version of each peer. And if its a legacy node, a trimmed down version of the block will be sent to it. Right?

Right.

> Is this stripping down of blocks happens on the fly? or both versions of the block are saved on the disk?

At least in Bitcoin Core, on the fly.